# How to control svg width using the space occupied by the text in the column flutter

Tags: flutter

How to control svg width using the space occupied by the text in the column.

What I want

[image] [image]

What I am getting-
[image]

```
Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(text),
        SvgPicture.asset(
          Assets.weirdLine,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Also tried with code-

```
Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(text),
        Container(
          height: 4,
          child: Expanded(
//            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              Assets.weirdLine,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

Comment: could you add your svg file too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get text width and set it to svg width.
use this code,

```
Size calcTextSize(String text, TextStyle style) {
final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
  text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  textScaleFactor: WidgetsBinding.instance.window.textScaleFactor,
)..layout();
return textPainter.size;
}

final double textWidth = calcTextSize(text, TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize)).width;
```